# Basic Animation Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

I need to do a crossfade animation between views for my project. Which is the best way to produce animation and creating views/windows which one is best. Suggest me a solutions for this work around? Am using Titanium 3.1.2.GA, Alloys and Android Emulator for my testing environment. Any examples may be appriciated? My [thread](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/157444/view-animation) in appcelerator forum

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="fblogin" class="container">
        <Require src="loginsuccess" id="loginsuccess"></Require>
        <Require src="loginFailure" id="loginFailure"></Require>
        <Require src="loginPage" id="loginPage"></Require>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**loginPage.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <LoginButton ns="Alloy.Globals.Facebook"/>
        <Button title="Google"></Button>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

**loginFailure.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <Label>Login Failed. Please try again later.</Label>
    </View>>
</Alloy>
```

**loginsuccess.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <Label>Login Successful</Label>     
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
var animation = require('alloy/animation');
var loginPage = $.loginPage;
var loginsuccess = $.loginsuccess;
var loginFailure = $.loginFailure;
function loginFails(){
    animation.crossFade(loginPage, loginFailure, 500, function(){});
}
function loginSuccess(){
    animation.crossFade(loginPage, loginsuccess, 500, function(){});
}
$.fblogin.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the problem description from your link:

> Now if I call loginFails() or loginSuccess(), then its showing error because its in controller Index and not in other view controller. How to solve this?

In order to reference an element *inside* a required view, you have to use getView('elementId').

**index.xml**

```xml
<Alloy>
    <Window id="fblogin" class="container">
        <Require src="loginsuccess" id="loginsuccess"></Require>
        <Require src="loginFailure" id="loginFailure"></Require>
        <Require src="loginPage" id="loginPage"></Require>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**loginsuccess.xml**

```xml
<Alloy>
    <View class="container" id="successContainer" visible="false">
        <Label>Login Successful</Label>     
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```js
var successView = $.loginsuccess.getView('successContainer');
```

You can now perform your crossfade on successView.

**Edit:**
Added visible="false" to the container view

Comment: Thank you mwfire. I will try and let you know.

Comment: mwfire -- This is showing loginFailure view after animation. If I rearrande index.xml as below  `<Require src="loginFailure" id="loginFailure"></Require><Require src="loginsuccess" id="loginsuccess"></Require><Require src="loginPage" id="loginPage"></Require>`, then its showing LoginSuccess view. Is anywhere am doing error?

Comment: I have not used the crossfade animation yet, but I assume that you have to set both views, loginSuccess and loginFailure, to `visible=false`. You can either do it in the corresponding .tss file, or directly in markup, like `<View class="container" id="successContainer" visible="false">`...

Comment: Am not having reputations to upvote mwfire. It works. Thanks alot. visible="false" makes it animate.